# Velocity templates in CKeditor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, wysiwyg, velocity

I am editing Velocity templates in CK editor, but it always changes the position of `#if #else #foreach` when opened. Is there a way to prevent it? I have already set the `config.allowedContent: true`

Comment: Hi, did you get the answer ?

Comment: No, I started using a normal text area if there are some #foreach #if.....